# Can anyone please give the reference for this hadith?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I hear a hadith from youtube from Omar Suleiman. Here is the link of the [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYAEyUKYzus)

That The prophet (saw) Was sitting with jibreel and suddenly the sky opened and angel israfil came.
seeing that jibreel become very afraid. The israfil angel ask prophet (saw), if he want to lead a rich life or stay in his poor life. He answered to stay in his poor life.

The hadith is something like that. I searched almost everywhere but can't find it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: There's no primary hadith source quoting a hadith where Israfil إِسرافيل appears (suddenly) and the provided information is hardly enough to do any good research. The only repeated hadith mentioning him is one where he appears in a du'a citing him among other known angels, The closest hadith I know of is that where the prophet has been asked whether he wants to be a king and prophet or a servant and prophet.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I updated my post with the video link of that video. Check it. maybe be you can find more information from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hadith in the video has been recorded in [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33037/3371#p1), [Dala'il al-Nubuwwah al-Bayhaqi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7478/468#p1), [Sahih ibn Hibban](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/9312), [Sunan al-Kubra an-Nasai](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33867/9329#p1), [Mu'jam al-Kabir Tabarani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/15519) etc. The wording of the narration in Musnad Ahmad is:

> جلس جبريل إلى النبي -صلى الله عليه وسلم-، فنظر إلى السماء، فإذا ملك ينزل، فقال جبريل: إن هذا الملك ما نزل منذ يوم خلق قبل الساعة، فلما نزل قال: يا محمد، أرسلني إليك ربك، قال: أفملكا نبيا يجعلك، أو عبدا رسولا؟، قال جبريل: تواضع لربك يا محمد، قال بل عبدا رسولا

Comment: Footnote here cites some other sources https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/5659

Comment: jajakallahu khair for the hadith. But can you kindly tell me hadith number from Musnad Ahmad. I checked your link but i don't understand arabic. But Musnad Ahmad hadith app. so if you can tell me the hadith number..

Comment: @DavidHarry Hadith numbers differ from publisher to publisher. It is number 7160 in the links above.

Comment: Thank you. That would be enough

Answer (score 0):

The hadeeth is authentic but without naming the angel who descended. The authentic hadeeth stated that it was an angel who had never descended to earth since he was created.